# Grab JSON Arrays in PHP from AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm sending an AJAX request with multiple arrays and I can't figure out how to grab the data?

This is what I'm sending:

[image]

I'm doing this through a jQuery AJAX POST to a PHP file.. How would one go about grabbing the data from here?

Thank you!

-- EDIT!!

This is the jQuery

```
var h1 = []
h2 = []
h3 = [],
layout = $( "input[type=radio][name='layout_option']:checked" ).val();

$("ul.widget-order[name='1'] li").each(function() {  h1.push($(this).attr('id'));  });
$("ul.widget-order[name='2'] li").each(function() {  h2.push($(this).attr('id'));  });
$("ul.widget-order[name='3'] li").each(function() {  h3.push($(this).attr('id'));  });

var sendData = JSON.stringify({
    ids1: " " + h1 + "",
    ids2: " " + h2 + "",
    ids3: " " + h3 + ""
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "_backend/account/updateWidgets.php",
    data: { data: sendData } + '&layout=' + layout,
    success: function( data ){
        $("#post_reply").html(data);
        console.log( { data: sendData } );
    )};
)};
```

Comment: What do you mean grab the data? PHP will see it as a $_POST variable.

Comment: @mkaatman I understand that, but what would one put after the $_POST? I'm trying this: $_POST['data'] but I'm not receiving anything?

Comment: Can you add the jQuery code you're using to send the POST? Also you can try `var_dump($_POST);` on the PHP side to see if it's actually empty.

Comment: @JDel Hi I've added the jQuery -- When I did `var_dump($_POST);` I received NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the post request to your Php file is successful you can access it by using the $_POST variable.

Comment: What would follow the $_POST variable though? I've tried $_POST['data'] and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: You will need to decode the json as the guy in the other answer said. What does json_decode($_POST); give you?

Comment: Doing: var_dump( $json_decoded) where $json_decoded = json_decode($_POST['data']) retrieves: NULL

Comment: @hdifen `$_POST` is an array, not JSON. `json_decode($_POST)` will never work.

Comment: @ImArron Ok your bug might be somewhere else then. Is your post successful? How are you sending the post? Is your webserver setup correctly?  Can you put your javascript thats making the post request in your question too? You can click on the bracers {} to format your text with code.

Comment: Hi @hdifen I've just added it now.

Comment: @ImArron Can you check if your Post is successful?  I haven't used jquery in a while but from memory it should throw an error in the console of chrome devtools if the post request failed to contact the server.

Comment: @hdifen The post is definitely successful because I can retrieve $_POST['layout'] just fine, I just can't retrieve any of the id arrays.

Comment: @ImArron Ok cool, that's important haha. I think the data you are sending is doing something funky. You are adding a string to an object and unless jquery handles that weirdly I don't think that would work. Can your try sending {'data': data, 'layout': layout}?  $_POST['data'] will include this object.

Answer (score 1):

To read the JSON encoded data on the PHP side:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decodedJSON = json_decode($json);

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hi @Russell I've added the code - would it be possible for you to have another look?

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['data']` contains JSON, so call `json_decode()`.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

Now you can access `$data['ids1']`, `$data['ids2']`, etc.

There isn't really any good reason to send the data as JSON. You could just put the original object directly in the jQuery `data:` option. Then you would could access the parameters as `$_POST['ids1']`, `$_POST['ids2']`, etc.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "_backend/account/updateWidgets.php",
  data: {
    ids1: " " + h1,
    ids2: " " + h2,
    ids3: " " + h3,
    layout: layout
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#post_reply").html(data);
    console.log({
      data: sendData
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Apologies @Barmar I've added the jQuery now, would it be possible for you to take another look?

Comment: Why do you concatenate a space at the front? And concatenating an empty string at the end is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I would recommend changing the way you are making the jQuery request to the following:

```
var h1 = []
h2 = []
h3 = [],
layout = $( "input[type=radio][name='layout_option']:checked" ).val();

$("ul.widget-order[name='1'] li").each(function() {  h1.push($(this).attr('id'));  });
$("ul.widget-order[name='2'] li").each(function() {  h2.push($(this).attr('id'));  });
$("ul.widget-order[name='3'] li").each(function() {  h3.push($(this).attr('id'));  });

var sendData = JSON.stringify({
    ids1: " " + h1 + "",
    ids2: " " + h2 + "",
    ids3: " " + h3 + ""
});
var sPayload = "data=" + encodeURIComponent(sendData) + "&layout=" + encodeURIComponent(layout);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "_backend/account/updateWidgets.php",
    data: sPayload,
    success: function( data ){
        $("#post_reply").html(data);
        console.log( { data: sendData } );
    }
});
```

There were a few syntax errors in code you posted which I have corrected in the code included in my answer, but most importantly, I have modified your data to being all of one encoding. It seems like you were trying to combine a JSON Object with standard data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I have standardized this in the code above so all data is posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In your PHP, you can then access this as:

```
<?php
// First, let's get the layout because that's the easiest
$layout = (isset($_POST['layout']) ? $_POST['layout'] : NULL);
// As a note, the isset(...) with ternary operator is just my preferred method for checking missing data when extracting that data from the PHP super-globals.

// Now we'll need to get the JSON portion.
$jData = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($jData, $assoc=true);

echo "ids1 is " . $data['ids1'] . "\n<br>\n";
echo "ids2 is " . $data['ids2'] . "\n<br>\n";
echo "ids3 is " . $data['ids3'] . "\n<br>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

I think have a mistake between data is property of ajax object and data is property in your post data.

Please post your jquery code.